# Problem generating data contract code with SVCUTIL

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, svcutil.exe, ogc

When i run the following command in the visual studio command prompt:

```
D:\Documents\DEV\SARPilot\Docs\eoschema\schema\OrderSchema>svcutil /t:code /language=C# *.wsdl *.xsd ..\ws-addressing\*.xsd ..\gml\3.1.1\base\*.xsd ..\ows\1.0.0\*.xsd ..\xlink\1.0.0\*.xsd ..\swe\sweCommon\0.0.0\*.xsd /out:MyServiceProxy.cs /config:MyServiceProxy.config
```

I get the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Error: Cannot read ..\ws-addressing\*.xsd.

    Cannot load file D:\Documents\DEV\SARPilot\Docs\eoschema\schema\ws-addressing\ws-addr.xsd as an Assembly. Check the FusionLogs
 for more Information.

    Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Documents\DEV\SARPilot\Docs\eoschema\schema\ws-addressing\ws-addr.xsd' or one of i
ts dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"
```

I'm using the following schema files:
http://wiki.services.eoportal.org/tiki-download_wiki_attachment.php?attId=637&page=HMA-FO%20Deliverables

How can i get past this error?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but try putting all the switches together, and then follow by all the file paths.

Comment: Nope, same thing, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so i've gotten past this error. (i get more now, but those are for another question).

I opened the ws-addr.xsd file in VS2010 and looked down the warnings list. one said:

> Warning   105 The XML editor tried to
>   convert this DTD to XSD so it can
>   provide validation and intellisense
>   while you type, but it could not
>   create a valid XSD schema.  Perhaps
>   this DTD uses constructs that do not
>   map to XSD.  You may be able to get
>   more information about the problem by
>   using the Create Schema
>   command.  D:\Documents\DEV\SARPilot\Docs\eoschema\schema\ws-addressing\ws-addr.xsd    3   11  D:...\schema\

So i man went to "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/ws-addr.xsd" and downloaded the correct one and replaced it.

I no longer got the warning 105, and no longer get the "Could not load file" error with svcutil